# hibernate reverse engineering character encoding

Tags: hibernate, character-encoding, reverse-engineering

Hi i am trying to reverse engineering with my oracle database but have a small problem that hibernate generates classnames in a unwanted encoding. for example if table name "KKYAGI"

my classname is "KkyAgı" here the "ı" is problem for me i want it as "KkyAgi". I know we can create a custom reverse engineering strategy with hibernate tools but i could not manage  to do with netbeans.

is there a easy way to do that or if i have to use hibernatetools anyone can help me with netbeans?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you run NetBeans on a machine with Turkish locale. If so, try to change locale used by NetBeans by changing `user.language` system property (note that it's a JVM system propery, not an environment variable).

I'm not sure how NetBeans startup works, but I think there should be some config where you can specify JVM properties, and you can write something like `-Duser.language=en` there.

Comment: By default, JVM will use the regional settings of the operating system. So i changed the regional settings but don't forget to restart netbeans lol i try without restarting thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For eclipse ide (hibernate tools)
Try adding -Duser.language=en in the bottom of your eclipse.ini which is found in your eclipse installation directory (keep a backup copy of the eclipse.ini before any changes).